# How to use IF in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand how to use `if` in SQL (in mySql).

I wrote this source code:

```
$query = "
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sec WHERE CHROM='1' AND POS='2')
    INSERT INTO sec (CHROM, POS) VALUES ('1','2')
END IF
";
mysqli_query($config, $query) or die('Eror: ' . mysqli_error($config));
```

and I got this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sec WHERE CHROM='1' AND POS='2') INSERT INTO se' at line 1
```

How should I correct the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question if you really want to use an IF-statement:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sec WHERE CHROM='1' AND POS='2')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sec (CHROM, POS) VALUES ('1','2')
END
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for IF here. You can simply do:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO sec (CHROM, POS) VALUES ('1','2')
```

The `IGNORE` keyword will tell mySql to treat duplicate key errors as mere warnings.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 better choice for the answer except IF statement:

-> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (if you have another value to be inserted)

-> INSERT IGNORE (if only you want to check duplicate or not)

You can check for the detail here:

["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)